# Will it cause memory leak or segfault when using CString

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have the following sample code:

```
CString CHttpsClient::converEncoding(LPWSTR originalString, long encodingType)
{
    if (encodingType == CP_ACP) {
        return CString(originalString);
    }
    CString ret;

    int nBufferSize = MultiByteToWideChar(encodingType, 0, (LPCCH)originalString, -1, NULL, 0); 
    wchar_t *pBuffer = (wchar_t*)malloc(nBufferSize * sizeof(wchar_t));
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCCH)originalString, -1, pBuffer, nBufferSize * sizeof(wchar_t));
    ret = CString(pBuffer);
    free(pBuffer); 
    return ret;
}
```

My question is when I invoke this method, I have freed memory of pBuffer, but this pBuffer still returned as CString(pBuffer), Will it cause memory leak or segfault when using CString like this?

Comment: "but this pBuffer still returned as CString(pBuffer)" - if that were the case your code would invoke *undefined behavior* as soon as someone (read: anyone) attempted to use that buffer after the free. The `CString` constructor you're does not take ownership of your buffer, it only uses it as a source of data for building its own. Fwiw, you can do this directly into the `CString` if you construct it by size via `GetBuffer`, do your conversion, then `ReleaseBuffer` and skip the middle man `pBuffer` entirely. See the `CString` docs for info on those members.

Answer (score 0):

So, I should use it like this, right?:

```
void CHttpsClient::converEncoding(CString& result, LPWSTR originalString, long encodingType)
{
    if (encodingType == CP_ACP) {
        return;
    }
    int nBufferSize = MultiByteToWideChar(encodingType, 0, (LPCCH)originalString, -1, NULL, 0); 
    wchar_t *pBuf = result.GetBuffer(nBufferSize * sizeof(wchar_t));
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCCH)originalString, -1, pBuf, nBufferSize * sizeof(wchar_t));
}

void CHttpsClient::someMethod(){
    CString text = _T("");
    converEncoding(text, _T("Hello StackOverflow"), utf-8);
    text.ReleaseBuffer();
}
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?